# Adding a second x axis to a TGraph in the CERN ROOT program

Tags: root-framework

does anyone know the method or code to add a second x axis to a TGraph in CERN's ROOT program? Ive been searching the root website and its documentation almost always confuses me. What i need is just one plot of data, but a second X axis on top whose values are a function of the bottom x axis' values. Its basically so lazy people dont have to convert from the numbers of the bottom x axis to the top x axis.

For a simple example (if i wasnt clear)

Say you have a sine curve which is some function of theta. On the top x axis we could have degrees whereas on the bottom we could have radians with 360deg corresponding to 2pi rad...

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

TGaxis is the class you are looking for to draw extra axes wherever you desire. Grabbing the world coordinate for your pad you can then superimpose like so. Replace `low` and `high` with the appropriate limits.

```
// your graph code here...
TGraph->Draw("AP");    

TGaxis *axis = new TGaxis(gPad->GetUxmin(),gPad->GetUymax(),gPad->GetUxmax(),gPad->GetUymax(),low,high,510,"+L");
axis->Draw();
```

Check out [TGaxis documentation](http://root.cern.ch/root/html534/TGaxis.html) for more examples.

Comment: Here the updated link https://root.cern/doc/master/classTGaxis.html

Answer (score 0):

(A previous answer I had was deleted as it was just a link to the site listed as a reference below. I hope this is more in line with the community guidelines.)

I think this might do what you want.

```
void axis2() {
   TH1F *h = new TH1F("h","test",30,-3,3);
   h->FillRandom("gaus",10000);
   h->Draw();
   TText t;
   t.SetTextSize(0.02);
   t.SetTextAlign(22);
   Double_t yt = - h->GetMaximum()/15.;   
   for (Int_t i=1;i<=30;i++) t.DrawText(h->GetBinCenter(i),yt,Form("%d",i%10));
```

}

It doesn't create another taxis but shows you how to draw text at the same location of the axis. The answer comes from Rene Brun himself (one of the main authors of root) so I don't think you can have two x axes.

Source: 
http://root.cern.ch/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=7110

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example showing how to proceed.
https://root.cern/doc/master/twoscales_8C.html